# JSP Tomcat8.15 No suitable for jdbc:jdbc:sqlserver error

Tags: jsp, jdbc

I use jdbc4 Driver for my jsp web project and I imported the jdbc4 jar.
And it run on my web site successful when I built and started with eclipse build start button, But It has an error when I exported war files and ran tomcat 8.5 for manual. The message is like :

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://ip:port

So I tried to put the `jdbc4.0.jar` in `tomcat8.15/lib` folder but it still invoke error. How should I gonna do? Why the manual tomcat run occur that jdbc error?

Comment: Is the installation directory included in the [CLASSPATH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver)?

Comment: @JeroenHeier There is no CLASSPATH enviroment var , So i put the sqljdbc4.0.jar in java / jre1.8 / ext  and i create new enviroment var [CLASSPATH] and set the javapath/jre1.8/ext/sqljdbc4.0.jar

Comment: But it still run in eclipse but not in manual tomcat

Comment: Don't put libraries in `lib/ext`, it is deprecated and will be removed. You will need to add the driver to the tomcat lib folder, or add it to your web project.

Comment: Your title suggests your URL is "jdbc:jdbc:sqlserver" (which would be very wrong), while your quoted error message says something different. Please edit your question so it is consistent, show the full stacktrace.

Comment: I import jdbc to project like Project - BuildPath - Add Jars - sqljdbc4.0.jar , And it is in Referenced Library in project explorer. But it still not work..